# WordPress - Add class to Widget text

Tags: wordpress

What is the way to add a text input inside "text widget" and data in text input will add to class of widget like

```
<aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text custom_class_here">
...
</aside>
```

my way is un-register widget text and re-create that. But i think will have better way. How to do that thanks

Comment: You can just install this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/ and you'll have the option to add Custom Classes & ID on each widgets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the functions.php file the sidebars are registered. e.g.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'description' => __( 'Appears on posts and pages except the optional Front Page template, which has its own widgets', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

What you want to do is to add the custom class in that `aside` e.g.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'description' => __( 'Appears on posts and pages except the optional Front Page template, which has its own widgets', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s my_custom_class_here">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Comment: sorry. But I want to add input text to `defaut widget text`? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the whole text and do string replacement or additions with:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'widget_so_25825107', 10, 2 );

function widget_so_25825107( $text, $instance ) {
    $new_text = "manipulate $text here";
    return $new_text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of adding a custom class to the Widgets Text field. Look for `some-other-class` and replace that with your own classes.

```php
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', [ new Sidebar_Filterer, 'filter' ], 10, 1 );

class Sidebar_Filterer {

    /**
     * @filter dynamic_sidebar_params 10 1
     *
     * @param $param
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function filter( $params ) {
        if ( ! is_array( $params ) || empty( $params ) ) {
            return $params;
        }

        foreach ( $params as &$param ) {
            if ( is_array( $param ) ) {
                $param = $this->filter_text_widget( $param );
            }
        }

        return $params;
    }

    private function filter_text_widget( array $param ): array {
        if ( ! array_key_exists( 'widget_name', $param ) ) {
            return $param;
        }

        if ( $param['widget_name'] != 'Text' ) {
            return $param;
        }

        if ( ! array_key_exists( 'before_widget', $param ) ) {
            return $param;
        }

        if ( strpos( $param['before_widget'], 'widget_text' ) === false ) {
            return $param;
        }

        $param['before_widget'] = str_replace( 'widget_text', 'widget_text some-other-class', $param['before_widget'] );

        return $param;
    }
}
```